# Using Date range parameter in the command

Tags: sql-server, parameters, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that contains a date range parameter (2 values). I want to use this parameter in the SQL command. Is there a way to achieve this : Here is how I want to use it :

```
--Query
Where 
(
    MyTable.Date between  
       Min({?Period_Filter})//Incorrect
       and 
       Max({?Period_Filter})//Incorrect
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll depend on your flavor of SQL. In PL/SQL, for example, you could do

`WHERE MyTable.Date between LEAST({?DATE}) AND GREATEST({?DATE})`

Although, I'd suggest using two separate parameters, `{?Start Date}` and `{?End Date}` instead of a single multi-valued parameter. It'll make everything easier and more user friendly.

`WHERE MyTable.Date between {?Start Date} and {?End Date}`